# Receive specific content via Share Intent in Android

Tags: android, text, android-intent, share, mime-types

As an example of what I am trying to do: when I share an article from Pocket to Evernote, Pocket formats the text and sends the full article to Evernote whereas when I share an article with my app, I simply receive the URL. I know that there is code being executed on Pocket's side as there is a "Processing" dialog before it shares.

My question: does Pocket know that it is sharing with Evernote and format its output specifically for Evernote, or does Evernote somehow register as a text editting app and therefore prompt Pocket to share the full article rather than just a URL?

If the latter, how is it done? Should I be registering my app to receive mime types other than `text/plain`? Here is a portion of the code I currently use to receive text:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rcvIntent = getIntent();
    String rcvAction = rcvIntent.getAction();
    String rcvType = rcvIntent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(rcvAction) && "text/plain".equals(rcvType))
        displaySentText(rcvIntent);
}
private void displaySentText (Intent rcvIntent) {
    String sharedText = rcvIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText == null) return;
    if (sharedText.startsWith("http://")) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageText().execute(sharedText);
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The debugger doesn't provide much information. When I share to Evernote, it shows:

```
02-27 16:36:50.005: I/ActivityManager(2257): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x80001 cmp=com.evernote/.note.composer.NewNoteAloneActivity (has clip) (has extras)} from pid 31094
```

And when I share to my app, I get a very similar message:

```
02-27 16:37:39.700: I/ActivityManager(2257): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x80001 cmp=st.olm.readmemberalpha/.WebText (has clip) (has extras)} from pid 31094
```

They are both text/plain, but the content is different. I have also checked the contents of the clip from `(has clip)` above, but the content is the same as the extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the pocket blog, it seems that Pocket does in fact specifically format the article text for Evernote. The share `intent` clip is from the [`ClipData` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html), and is simply a duplicate of the extra and is used instead since api 11.

It would seem that there is no way–at least via share intents, and to my knowledge–to coerce another app into providing specific data (types).